# Prevent using same query twice, once in each view composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two `View` composers in my `AppServiceProvider` class, below:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('left', function ($view)
        {
            if (Auth::check())
            {
                $user = Auth::user();

                // Gets a list of the people the user is following
                $usersFollowing = Following::where('user_id', $user->id)
                    ->get();

                // More queries here

                View::share('usersFollowing', $usersFollowing);
            }
        });

        View::composer('right', function ($view)
        {
            if (Auth::check())
            {
                $user = Auth::user();

                // Gets a list of the people the user is following
                $usersFollowing = Following::where('user_id', $user->id)
                    ->get();

                // More queries here

                View::share('usersFollowing', $usersFollowing);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, both composers request the same query data (`$usersFollowing`). Both of these layouts (`left.blade.php` and `right.blade.php`) are called on all of my pages (by including them in the base layout).

The problem with this is that the page is requesting `$usersFollowing` twice on a single page load. It's calling the query once for `left.blade.php` and once for `right.blade.php`.

I'm also calling `Auth::user()` twice, once in each composer.

How can I prevent these queries from being called twice for the same request, and only call it once?

Answer (score -1):

I think it is simple to move your queries to top of your method and use them inside both View composers. This way your query would only run once. 
Here is my proposed way of doing this;

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        // Gets a list of the people the user is following
        $usersFollowing = Following::where('user_id', $user->id)
                    ->get();
        // You can use `use` keyword to access external variables inside callback function. 
        //Both of these variables will be accessible inside callback
        View::composer('left', function ($view) use ($usersFollowing,$user)
        {
            if (Auth::check())
            {

                // More queries here

                View::share('usersFollowing', $usersFollowing);
            }
        });

        View::composer('right', function ($view) use ($usersFollowing,$user)
        {
            if (Auth::check())
            {

                // More queries here

                View::share('usersFollowing', $usersFollowing);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I hope this can be helpful and you can generalize this method to any other situations where you need this kind of functionality.